# Insert byte in a byte Array?

Tags: c#

byte[] myFile = File.ReadAllBytes("d:\123.xml");
I want insert some character after each byte in myFile byte array.
If the myFile byte array length is 5000, after insert, it will become 10000.
How can I write by c# ?

Comment: You can create another array, twice as big, then iterate through `myFile` and for each byte copy the value to new array and then add the required byte after it. You might find that it is easier to use `List<byte>` for that kind of work. If you need to work on same byte array then you need to preallocate the array twice as long as file and work in reverse order.

Comment: Given any research will have showed up that you cannot resize an array, what else have you tried?

Comment: if you insert a character after every byte your file will be three times larger.

Comment: This looks like a school assignment, I'd suggest doing it yourself, it's the only way to learn. Also if you're stuck, it's fine to ask but try typing what you tried and being specific about what you're having trouble with. Otherwise you're likely to get down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newArr = new int[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        newArr[i] = myFile[i / 2];
    }
    else
    {
        newArr[i] = (byte)someChar;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will crash. You need to calculate the old index based on the new in your if-branch.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. I've changed code

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *insert* into an array. An array is fixed length.

You can use a `List<byte>` if you want to insert specific bytes or you can use the power of LinQ to build a new array.

This will insert a nul byte after each byte you already have for example:

```
var inserted = myFile.SelectMany( b => new []{ b, (byte)0 } ).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but   "   (byte)0  " in your code fragment will not run

Comment: the error : Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @user2207102 Sorry, forgot a pair of brackets.

Comment: Using the `SelectMany` here is something very very... Very! :-)